# How to invert windows colors with VBScript or Batch-file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, colors

How do you invert windows with a VBScript or batch file? It doesn't need to invert it could be another effect like greyscale. I need to make it look a bit like a disco so loop. I haven't tried with batch-file because I am still a beginner. I am also a beginner to VBScript.
I have tried;

```
windows.color.invert
```

and I tried windows 10 shortcut

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
do 
wscript.sleep 100 
wshshell.sendkeys "{CTRL}"
wshshell.sendkeys "{WINDOWS}"
wshshell.sendkeys "{C}"
loop
```

I can do this but it will open and display it. Also it may crash with loop.

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"ms-settings:easeofaccess-highcontrast"
WScript.Sleep 2500
shell.SendKeys" "
WScript.Sleep 1500
shell.SendKeys"%{F4}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
```

I am not sure if I did the buttons correctly but I tried writing control too. Pls, help(I don't know how to code well).

Comment: I have found out that control is ^. Found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx. But the windows key isn't supported so that method is gone.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to invert? a window, a console??

Comment: Probably the Windows desktop color scheme, for a prank, judging from an earlier (now deleted) question.

Comment: I am trying to invert the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using the registry editor, you can change the magnifier invert value while magnifier is open.

```
set append=00000001
set key=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ScreenMagnifier
set value=Invert
set oldVal=0
for /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%r in ('reg query %key% /v %value%') do set 
oldVal=%%r
echo previous=%oldVal%
set newVal=%oldVal%%append% 
reg add %key% /v %value% /d %newVal% /f /t REG_DWORD
pause
```